# vuejs how to get get all routes after add router dynamiclly

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

New to vuejs, so there is a constant router object

```
const constantRouterMap = [{
a,b,c }]
```

and imported  to Router object

```
new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  ...
  ......
  routes: constantRouterMap
})
```

And I have also added routers in a js file

```
import router from '@/router'
.......
.....
router.addRoutes(dynamicRouters)
```

Then I tried to get all routes with

```
router.options.routes
```

or

```
getRoutes()
```

But this only gives me 3 routes  from constantRouterMap .
How can I get all routes included the routes I created dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're calling `getRoutes()` *after* you added the additional routes? Are you getting any errors? Are any of the the new routes overwriting existing routes?

Working code:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: { template: '<div/>' }
    }
  ]
})

router.addRoute({
  path: '/bar',
  component: { template: '<div/>' }
})

// Log the paths of each route
console.log(router.getRoutes().map(r => r.path))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mooon, could you please check problem of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686564/dynamically-registered-route-is-not-working-when-it-is-just-pushed